# Mi documento HTML no reconoce estilos internos

Tags: xhtml

Buenas tardes:

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en HTML y CSS. Dispongo del siguiente código pero el navegador no reconoce la información contenida entre las etiquetas STYLE. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

¡Gracias por vuestra atención!

```
    <head>

        <meta ... Los metatags van aquí ... >

        <base href="http://www.videotutoriales.com/html">

        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120;URL=http://www.trueachievements.com">

        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">

        <meta name="description" content="Videotutoriales online y por descarga directa">

        <meta name="keywords" content="Videos, tutoriales, videotutoriales">

        <title> Séptimo Continente &copy; </title>

        <LINK rel="hoja de estilo" href="nombre hoja de estilo externa"
        type="text/css">

        <style>

            body {
            background-color: blue;
            }

        </style>

        <script>

            ... Los scripts del lado clientelar van aquí ...

        </script>

        <body>


            <img src="https://www.videotutoriales.com/html/images/logo.png">

            <p> La página ha sido cambiada de ubicación. Serás redireccionado al nuevo
            'website' en tres segundos o también puedes pulsar el enlace inferior. </p>
            <a href="http://www.trueachievements.com"> TrueAchievements.COM </a>

        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: A mi me funciona bien, copie todo el codigo y sale el fondo azul y el mensaje, que error tienes mas especifico?

Comment: Es medio complicado ayudarte con tan poca información. ese se exactamente tu codigo ?  LINK mayuscula puede ser ? el path esta correcto ? etc

Comment: También lo he probado y el fondo me aparece de color azul a pesar de tener varios errores menores en las etiquetas, pero, al menos, el chrome si muestra bien los estilos.

Comment: tal vez la caché? prueba `ctrl + F5`

Comment: Tu problema no se puede reproducir: https://jsfiddle.net/pb5vec7e/ Revisa esta guía __[mcve]__ y modifica tu pregunta de forma apropiada.

Answer (score 2):

No has cerrado la etiqueta `<head>` por lo que veo. Tienes que meter el `<style>` antes de la etiqueta de `<title>` dentro del `<head>`. Y fijarte en cerrar las etiquetas

Comment: Aunque es una buena observación, no debería afectar.

Comment: yo copie y pegue tal cual el codigo y funciona perfectamente

Comment: yo he leido el codigo, y antes de probar me he fijado en esos detalles.